# Angular expressions take if condition?

Tags: angularjs

I read on the angular guide that the expressions cannot evaluate conditions.

I have a `var $scope.a = 2;` in by controller

On the partials if I do :
`ng-show={{a==2}}` --- then the ng-show becomes a truthy which is correct

but if I do :
`ng-if={{a==2}}` -- then this does not display

Why the change in behaviour of expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-if needs an expression, but your binding it to an expression result.

this works:

```
<div ng-if="1==1">visible</div>
<div ng-if="1==2">not visible</div>
```

The reason the behaviour differs is because the ng-if has a priority of 600. while the the ng-show has no priority. If i remove the priority from the directive it is able to use the bindings as value, but breaks on something else, so thats why they added the priority.

High prio gets compiled first, so the directive gets executed before the {{expression}} is evaluated to something javascript can understand.

From the angular docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

> priority
>
> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number. Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

Comment: actually ng-shows expect expression as well I think you or me misunderstand the question... for me the question why it is not working with ng-if while it is working with ng-show?

Comment: @wickY26 - Xcatly that is my question. Why is it working for ng-show and not ng-if

Comment: Yeah, i misunderstood. I found it though, so changed my answer.

Comment: Thank you. So what is the correct way {{}} or no {{}}

Comment: And why does the documentation state that expressions do not do conditional thingys

Comment: Because its not needed i would do it without the {{}}.

Comment: and how does the priority affect the way it binds the values ? I new to angular therefore have no idea about the priority

Comment: Where does it day this in the documentation? Maybe they mean its not a good practice because (complex) logic should be in the controller.

Comment: High prio goes first, so the directive gets executed before the {{expression}} is evaluated to something javascript can understand.

Comment: You cannot write a control flow statement in an expression. The reason behind this is core to the Angular philosophy that application logic should be in controllers, not the views. If you need a conditional, loop, or to throw from a view expression, delegate to a JavaScript method instead.

Comment: Hmm, that is confusing. I think they mean you cant do more complex things like if/else constructions. But i agree its not very clear.

Comment: It is the reason. Remove the prio from the ng-if directive in the angular source and you will see he is able to use the {{}} expression.

Comment: no it is definitely not related with priority... when you delete priority from the source code you actually change ng-if to something else... it does not create new scope anymore...

Comment: With priority 600 i break in the ng-if with the value:
    $attr.ngIf: "{{1==1}}"

If i change the prio to 0 I break in the ng-if with the value:
    $attr.ngIf: "true"

My conclusion: The reason for the difference between how ng-show and ng-if evaluate the expression is because of the execution order based on the priority. 

The directive itself breaks when you fiddle with the prio, so I'm not saying you should change it or anything.